# Organization Chart - Group by Manager to show all employees under him

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have written below code to display employee-manager reporting, i have group by so that all employees under one manager should be shown, but it is showing only 1 employee. what i am missing ?

LINQ Group By Logic-

```
var emp = (from m in employee
                       group m by m.ManagerId into g
                       join e1 in employee on g.FirstOrDefault().ManagerId equals e1.EmpId into temp
                       from t1 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()                       
                       select new 
                       {
                           EmpId = g.FirstOrDefault().EmpId,
                           EmployeeName = g.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeName,
                           Gender = g.FirstOrDefault().Gender,
                           ManagerId = t1?.ManagerId ?? 0  ,
                           ManagerName = t1?.EmployeeName ?? "Top of the Chain",
                           Designation = g.FirstOrDefault().Designation
                       }).ToList();
```

I have added implementation of AddEmployee() and RemoveEmployee() as below and calling as below, but Removeemployee does not remove employee from hierarchy ??

```
employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 11, EmployeeName = "Chris Harris", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Executive" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 13, EmployeeName = "Rocky Balbo", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = null, Designation = "CEO" });

            int? ceo = null;

            AddEmployee(new Employee { EmpId = 2, EmployeeName = "Rohan Kumar", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 13, Designation = "Application Architect"  });
            AddEmployee(new Employee { EmpId = 1, EmployeeName = "Mohan Kumar", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 2, Designation = "Tech Lead" });
            RemoveEmployee(new Employee { EmpId = 9, EmployeeName = "Rogger Binny", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Sales Executive" });
            GetHierarchy(ceo, 0, "");

   static void AddEmployee(Employee empDetails)
        {
            employee.Add(empDetails);
        }

        static void RemoveEmployee(Employee empDetails)
        {
            employee.Remove(empDetails);
        }
```

---

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    }

List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 3, EmployeeName = "Andrea Ely", Gender = 'F', ManagerId = 6, Designation = "Tech Head"});
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 4, EmployeeName = "John Eward", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 3, Designation = "General" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 5, EmployeeName = "Lesli Mac", Gender = 'F', ManagerId = 3, Designation = "Staff" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 6, EmployeeName = "Satinder Singh", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 13, Designation = "President" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 7, EmployeeName = "Amit Sarna", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 13, Designation = "Vice President" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 8, EmployeeName = "David Steward", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "General" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 9, EmployeeName = "Rogger Binny", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Sales Executive" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 10, EmployeeName = "Emy jackson", Gender = 'F', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Sales Executive" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 11, EmployeeName = "Chris Harris", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Executive" });
            employee.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 13, EmployeeName = "Rocky Balbo", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = null, Designation = "CEO" });

var emp = (from m in employee
                       group m by m.ManagerId into g
                       join e1 in employee on g.FirstOrDefault().ManagerId equals e1.EmpId into temp
                       from t1 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()                       
                       select new 
                       {
                           EmpId = g.FirstOrDefault().EmpId,
                           EmployeeName = g.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeName,
                           Gender = g.FirstOrDefault().Gender,
                           ManagerId = t1?.ManagerId ?? 0  ,
                           ManagerName = t1?.EmployeeName ?? "Top of the Chain",
                           Designation = g.FirstOrDefault().Designation
                       }).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("--------------Printing Manager-Employee Hierarchy-------------");
            foreach (var empDetails in emp)
            {               
                Console.WriteLine("Emp Name is {0} ManagerName is {1}", empDetails.EmployeeName, empDetails.ManagerName);                
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursive algorithm :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Employee> employees;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            employees = new List<Employee>();
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 3, EmployeeName = "Andrea Ely", Gender = 'F', ManagerId = 6, Designation = "Tech Head"});
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 4, EmployeeName = "John Eward", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 3, Designation = "General" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 5, EmployeeName = "Lesli Mac", Gender = 'F', ManagerId = 3, Designation = "Staff" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 6, EmployeeName = "Satinder Singh", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 13, Designation = "President" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 7, EmployeeName = "Amit Sarna", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 13, Designation = "Vice President" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 8, EmployeeName = "David Steward", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "General" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 9, EmployeeName = "Rogger Binny", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Sales Executive" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 10, EmployeeName = "Emy jackson", Gender = 'F', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Sales Executive" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 11, EmployeeName = "Chris Harris", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = 7, Designation = "Executive" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { EmpId = 13, EmployeeName = "Rocky Balbo", Gender = 'M', ManagerId = null, Designation = "CEO" });

            int? ceo = null;
            GetHierarchy(ceo, 0, "");

        }
        static void GetHierarchy(int? managerID, int level, string managerName)
        {
            List<Employee> group = employees.Where(x => x.ManagerId  == managerID).ToList();
            foreach (Employee empDetails in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}Emp Name is {1} ManagerName is {2}", new string(' ', 5 * level), empDetails.EmployeeName, managerName);
                GetHierarchy(empDetails.EmpId, level + 1, empDetails.EmployeeName);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Just the number of spaces to ident at each level.  It is equivalent to a tab at each level.

Comment: Can you look at my modified post, i have added AddEmployee() and RemoveEmployee(), RemoveEmployee() does not work ?  Can you please have a look ?

Comment: RemoveAll will not remove children of the employee that are deleted.  So any child of the removed employee not long has a manager.  If you remove a manager you have to take the immediate children and give them a new manager.

Comment: If i am using RemoveAll whole chain gets deleted, rather it should only delete that manager/emp and all of its children should start report to his upline manager. How we can achieve that in above code ?

Comment: RemoveAll does nothing for you.  Just use Remove.  Before removing you have to find all children and change their managers to the manage of the employee you are removing.

Answer (score 1):

**Update as per comment**

When calling `RemoveEmployee` your are create a new `object`, that's mean a new reference in memory. then the two `objects` are not equal(The object in `employee` list and the new `object`), but the values(values of `empId`...) are the same.

To delete element from `employee`, you have two solutions:
1 - use `RemoveAll`, and filtering by `empId` or create an other method that take `empId`, like the following code:

```
void RemoveEmployee(Employee empDetails)
{
    employee.RemoveAll(emp => emp.EmpId == empDetails.EmpId);
}
void RemoveEmployee(int empId)
{
    employee.RemoveAll(emp => emp.EmpId == empId);
}
```

2 - Filter when calling your `RemoveEmployee`, like the following code:

```
RemoveEmployee(employee.First(emp => emp.EmpId == 9));
```

**Old solution**

If in understand correctly, the problem here is with `ManagerName`, your code is good, but you need to avoid `FirstOrdDefault` to get the expected result,by looping for each element in `g`, like the following code:

```
var groupedEmp = (from m in employee
            group m by m.ManagerId into g
            join e1 in employee on g.Key equals e1.EmpId into temp
            from t1 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                g = g,
                t1 = t1
            });

var empList = groupedEmp
           .SelectMany(x => x.g.Select(y =>
                new Employee
                {
                    EmpId = y.EmpId,
                    EmployeeName = y.EmployeeName,
                    Designation = y.Designation,
                    Gender = y.Gender,
                    ManagerId = y.ManagerId ?? 0,
                    ManagerName = x.t1?.EmployeeName ?? "Top"
                })).ToList();
```

**Test**

```
foreach(Employee employe in empList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"EmpId  :  {employe.EmpId}, EmpName  :  {employe.EmployeeName}, MngId  :  {employe.ManagerId}, MngName  :  {employe.ManagerName}");
}
```

**Result**

```
EmpId  :  3, EmpName  :  Andrea Ely, MngId  :  6, MngName  :  Satinder Singh
EmpId  :  4, EmpName  :  John Eward, MngId  :  3, MngName  :  Andrea Ely
EmpId  :  5, EmpName  :  Lesli Mac, MngId  :  3, MngName  :  Andrea Ely
EmpId  :  6, EmpName  :  Satinder Singh, MngId  :  13, MngName  :  Rocky Balbo
EmpId  :  7, EmpName  :  Amit Sarna, MngId  :  13, MngName  :  Rocky Balbo
EmpId  :  8, EmpName  :  David Steward, MngId  :  7, MngName  :  Amit Sarna
EmpId  :  9, EmpName  :  Rogger Binny, MngId  :  7, MngName  :  Amit Sarna
EmpId  :  10, EmpName  :  Emy jackson, MngId  :  7, MngName  :  Amit Sarna
EmpId  :  11, EmpName  :  Chris Harris, MngId  :  7, MngName  :  Amit Sarna
EmpId  :  13, EmpName  :  Rocky Balbo, MngId  :  0, MngName  :  Top
```

i hope this help.

Comment: @user662285 can you try my solution?

Comment: Thanks,your solution works, now i am facing issue with RemoveEmployee() see implementation above

Comment: @user662285, you cant delete element by creating a new object, please check my proposition

Comment: @jsajid: If i am using RemoveAll whole chain gets deleted, rather it should only delete that manager/emp and all of its children should start reporting to his upline manager. How we can achieve that in above code ?

Comment: @user662285 Note that, ``RemoveAll`` take a condition, then not will delete the whole employee, you can also use your own function and call it like this:``RemoveEmployee(employee.First(emp => emp.EmpId == 9));`` but you can't create a new employee when you want to delete it.

Comment: It deletes whole chain