# Filter hierarchical list retaining parent using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

I have a model class which looks something like this:

```
public class Employee
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Designation {get;set;}
}
```

using which I simulated a list:

```
new List<Employee> employees
{
    new Employee{Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "A", Designation = "CEO" },
    new Employee{Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "B", Designation = "Manager" },
    new Employee{Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "C", Designation = "Manager" },
    new Employee{Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "D", Designation = "Lead" },
    new Employee{Id = 5, ParentId = 3, Name = "E", Designation = "Lead" },
    new Employee{Id = 6, ParentId = 4, Name = "F", Designation = "Developer" },
    new Employee{Id = 7, ParentId = 4, Name = "G", Designation = "Developer" },
    new Employee{Id = 8, ParentId = 5, Name = "H", Designation = "Developer" }
};
```

Well I need to write a LINQ query to filter the above list so that even the parent objects(if present) are retained during the filtering. I could not quiet wrap my head around the retainment of the parent part where I always end up getting it wrong.

To make it more clear this is what is the expected filtered list in case the filter search criteria are the Ids **6 and 7**:

```
{
    new Employee{Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "A", Designation = "CEO" },
    new Employee{Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "B", Designation = "Manager" },
    new Employee{Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "D", Designation = "Lead" }
    new Employee{Id = 6, ParentId = 4, Name = "F", Designation = "Developer" },
    new Employee{Id = 7, ParentId = 4, Name = "G", Designation = "Developer" }
}
```

and if the Id to filter is **8**:

```
{
    new Employee{Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "A", Designation = "CEO" },
    new Employee{Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "C", Designation = "Manager" },
    new Employee{Id = 5, ParentId = 3, Name = "E", Designation = "Lead" },
    new Employee{Id = 8, ParentId = 5, Name = "H", Designation = "Developer" }
}
```

and if the Id to filter is **2**:

```
{
    new Employee{Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "A", Designation = "CEO" },
    new Employee{Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "B", Designation = "Manager" }
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile, `Employee` doesn't have and `Id` property. Why filter for Ids 6 and 7 returns items with 1,2 and 4 values?

Comment: Well that was a demo class and list which I created for this question. Have updated in the question thanks for pointing

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski If you notice the Employee with Id 4 is the Parent for Employee with Ids 6 and 7. The Employee with Id 2 is the Parent for Employee with Id 4 and Employee with Id 1 is Parent for Id 2. Hope I am clear

Comment: You need a recursive algorithm.  Linq is meant for a flat architecture.  You have to build a tree structure and then the filter is a branch of the tree.

Comment: @jdweng You have a point here. That might probably be the reason why I was not able to find a solution to this

Comment: I don't think there is a easy filter for this. I would suggest to write a loop implementation of a function. As arguments it takes your list of employees and a list of ids. Then filter the employee list, so that all employees with a parent id contained in the list of ids are returned. Add those new ids to the list of ids and rerun the method until no more ids are added.

Comment: @Rennnyyy Well frankly speaking the data which I need to filter on is pretty huge so wanted to do it as efficiently as possible

Comment: @SurajNair it's seems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872259/organization-chart-group-by-manager-to-show-all-employees-under-him/60874724#60874724

Comment: You may want to look at Tree filtering algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a help method, `EmployeeAndBosses` which returns given employee and all the parents:

```
private static IEnumerable<Employee> EmployeeAndBosses(Employee value, 
                                                       IEnumerable<Employee> collection) {
  for (Employee item = value; 
       item != null; 
       item = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParentId == item.Id))
    yield return item; 
}
```

then you can filter *topmost* employee in the hierarchy, and add their bosses then:

```
HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>() {
  6, 7
}; 

var result = employees
  .Where(item => ids.Contains(item.Id))                   // topmost
  .SelectMany(item => EmployeeAndBosses(item, employees)) // topmost and parents
  .GroupBy(item => item.Id)          // Duplicates (e.g. CEO) removing
  .Select(group => group.First());   //
```

**Edit:** If you have a huge collection(s) and that's why `FirstOrDefault` and `GroupBy` are bad choice, you can implement Bread First Search:

```
private static IEnumerable<Employee> MyFilter(IEnumerable<Employee> list, 
                                              IEnumerable<int> idsToFind) {
  Dictionary<int, Employee> stuff = list
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Id, item => item);

  HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(idsToFind);

  HashSet<int> completed = new HashSet<int>(); 
  Queue<Employee> agenda = new Queue<Employee>(list.Where(item => ids.Contains(item.Id)));

  while (agenda.Count > 0) {
    Employee current = agenda.Dequeue();

    if (null != current && completed.Add(current.Id)) {
      yield return current;

      if (stuff.TryGetValue(current.ParentId, out current))
        agenda.Enqueue(current);
    }
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As some comments seem to be quite... Subjective... Here is a simple (but somewhat inefficient) extension that handles your requirements like a charm: 
*(assuming you'll never hire an employee as a boss to another employee that in turn is their boss, but such madness would probably break the company quicker than it breaks the query)*

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<Employee> FindByIdsAndIncludeParents(this IEnumerable<Employee> employees, params int[] targetIds)
        => employees
            .Where(r => targetIds.Contains(r.Id))
            .SelectMany(r => employees.FindByIdsAndIncludeParents(r.ParentId).Append(r))
        .Distinct();
```

As some are not quite as keen of exchanging this quite expensive operation for the mere beauty of it, we could trade in some beauty for speed using a dictionary as entry point for instant access to the appended boss-search:

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<Employee> FindFriendsFaster(this IEnumerable<Employee> employees, params int[] targetIds) 
        => employees
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Id, e => e)
            .FindWithBossFriend(targetIds)
        .Distinct();

    public static IEnumerable<Employee> FindWithBossFriend(this IDictionary<int, Employee> hierarchy, params int[] targetIds)
            => targetIds
                .Where(eId => hierarchy.ContainsKey(eId))
                .Select(eId => hierarchy[eId])
                .SelectMany(e => hierarchy.FindWithBossFriend(e.ParentId).Append(e));
```

As you might be able to spot, I personally can't seem to be able to trade in any more of my dignity for the possible removal of that last .Distinct(), but there are rumors going around some would be.